# TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Object'

Tags: java, html, css, angular, typescript

I try to post datas by using templateDrivenForm directly and get datas from fireBase but show the following type error.

My part of codes

```
//directly posts datas using submitButton from templateDrivenForm
 onCreatePosts(postDatas:{title:string, content:string}){
this.http.post('https://ng-complete-guide-b3d7f-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/posts.json',
 postDatas)
.subscribe(
 responseData => {
  console.log(responseData);
 });
 }

 //get datas from database
   private fetchPost(){
     return this.http.get('https://ng-complete-guide-b3d7f-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/posts.json')
   .pipe(map(responseData =>  {
     const dataArray = [];
    for(let key in responseData){
    if(responseData.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    dataArray.push({...responseData[key], id:key});
    }
  }
  return dataArray;
 }))
  .subscribe( responseData => {
  console.log(responseData)
 })
}
```

My error is

```
     Error: src/app/app.component.ts:40:28 - error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type 
      because 
     expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Object'.
      No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Object'.

     40         dataArray.push({...responseData[key], id:key});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution

```
      private fetchPost(){
      return this.http.get('https://ng-complete-guide-b3d7f-default- 
      rtdb.firebaseio.com/posts.json')
    .pipe(map((responseData:{[data:number]:any}) =>  {
     const dataArray = [];
     for(let key in responseData){
  if(responseData.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    dataArray.push({...responseData[key], id:key});
  }
  }
    return dataArray;
  }))
 .subscribe( responseData => {
  console.log(responseData)
 })
 }

 .pipe(map((responseData:{[data:number]:any}) //object type
```

Comment: i think your id is a string and you should avoid using `any` as much as possible.  the type should be `{ [key:string]: { content: string, title: string } }`

Comment: Can you consolidate the posts object (at least partially) in your function and show which fields come? But in your place, instead of using the REST API (it is very limited compared to the library), I would suggest using a special library for working with firebase for angular https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/fire

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase nested object can be converted to this data type in the map function:
**responseData:{[key:string]:any}**

```js
private fetchPosts() {
   this.http
     .get('https://ng-complete-guide-b3d7f-default- 
     rtdb.firebaseio.com/posts.json')
     .pipe(map(
       (responseData:{[key:string]:any}) => {
       const dataArray = [];
       for (const key in responseData) {
         if(responseData.hasOwnProperty(key)){
           dataArray.push({ ...responseData[key], id:key})
         }
       }
       return dataArray;
     }))
     .subscribe(posts => {
       console.log(posts);
     });
 }
```

I agree that we should avoid using 'any' as much as possible. If you find a more accurate type compilable with the latest Angular version, please share it!